How do I trace back a dead outlet?
I have a dead outlet that I can't quite figure out. It's a GFCI outlet about 10 feet from the breaker panel (in the same room). It is (as far as I know) the only outlet that is dead in the house.
Several non-contact voltage testers, a plug-in tester, and a volt meter have confirmed that there is no voltage at the plug. I have a circuit tracer that sends an audible tone up the wire to find the breaker, but it requires an energized circuit to work.
Is there a good way to trace this circuit in the current condition? I'm hoping to not open the wall any more than necessary.

Did you check for voltage at the wires inside the junction box for the outlet?

Also: How can I trace an electrical cable?, How can I trace cable through floors and walls?, and more.

There are professional versions of the circuit tracer that power the transmitter with a battery and do not require that the outlet be live. They appear on eBay fairly frequently. Not cheap, but when it's the tool you need...

My Extech TG20 was inexpensive and worked decently to trace wires.  Would I call it professional quality?  No, but it worked well enough for my purpose.

Important:
The non contact testers only work if you have power.
Turn off the breaker, disconnect the wiring at the plug, otherwise you get false reading.
Then use one of these tracers.
They have internal power (a 9 volt battery) that is used for the Non Contact tester to detect discontinuous wire.

From the question: to find the breaker - so disconnect the wiring on both ends is not an option.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact `have a dead outlet that I can't quite figure out. It's a GFCI outlet about 10 feet from the breaker panel (in the same room). It is (as far as I know) the only outlet that is dead in the house.
Several non-contact voltage testers, a plug-in tester, and a volt meter have confirmed that there is no voltage at the plug. I have a circuit tracer that sends an audible tone up the wire to find the breaker, but it requires an energized circuit to work.`

@Traveler that quote is agnostic on whether the OP actually knows which breaker serves the outlet, though.

@Huesmann: Yes - and the phrasing "to find the breaker" at least suggests OP is indeed trying to find the breaker.

I do not know which breaker is supposed to serve that outlet. I presume the hot side is at least disconnected somewhere in between the breaker and the outlet as the non-contact testers indicate no voltage.

@Elros use the tester I recommended than turn off breakers one by one and test
